# How do I change how often pythons webdriverwait explicit wait checks?

Tags: python, selenium

I’ve been looking online for ages now, I’m looking for the equivalent of a fluent wait with selenium for java. I need to be able to change how often webdriverwait checks for an expected condition. Any ideas? The default is 500 milliseconds and I need it to be faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the source code

```
POLL_FREQUENCY = 0.5  # How long to sleep inbetween calls to the method
IGNORED_EXCEPTIONS = (NoSuchElementException,)  # exceptions ignored during calls to the method


class WebDriverWait(object):
    def __init__(self, driver, timeout, poll_frequency=POLL_FREQUENCY, ignored_exceptions=None):
```

So you need to set the `poll_frequency` parameter

Comment: Thank you very much, that was very quick! I’ll play around with this. Much appreciated Tarun.

Comment: @TomasWooller, Since you are new SO, just wanted to let you know that you should mark the answer that helped you solved the issue as an accepted answer. This can be done by clicking on tick button near upvotes. Also you can do one time upvotes to appreciate an answer. This is valid for questions and answer from anyone else too

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned in your question about pythons `WebDriverWait` i.e. `Explicit Wait` and need to check the `webdriverwait` faster.

The [**`documentation`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) of **`WebDriverWait`** mentions as follows:

```
class selenium.webdriver.support.wait.WebDriverWait(driver, timeout, poll_frequency=0.5, ignored_exceptions=None)
```

where :

- **`poll_frequency`** - sleep interval between calls By default, it is 0.5 second

So in order to modify the **`WebDriverWait`** and make it faster, we can reduce the **`poll_frequency`** from default setting of **`0.5`** to **`0.4`**, **`0.3`**, **`0.2`**, **`0.1`** etc values as per our requirement.